# Conditional validation using abide in rails?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation, client-side-validation

I have two fields and i need to check at least one field has value rather than validating both. Say for example i need either `phone number` field or `email` field to be filled. How can i do this using `foundation` abide? Please help me

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to implement a backend validation, but do it on the client? I just stumbled over [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/). you are able to add custom validators with this easily.